# Unexpected behavior of selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser

**Meta :-**

- Firefox v51.0.1 (32-bit)
- IE v11.576.14393.0
- IE
- Windows 10
- Selenium 3.0.1
- Geckodriver Win32 v0.13.0
- IEDriverServer Win32 v3.0.0
- Java v1.8.0_71

**Steps to reproduce :-**

- When I use below code it launches `Firefox` browser :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
  ```
- When I use below code it launches `IE` browser :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/iedriverserver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
  ```

---

**Questions :-**

- Why `selenium` opens browser on the basis of `executable driver` setting?
- Is in both case selenium behavior is correct?
- If correct then why we have separate driver class name like `FirefoxDriver`, `InternetExplorerDriver`, `ChromeDriver` etc?

Comment: Do you mean to say that `Firefox & IE` instead of `Chrome`, because of `driver executable`? If Yes, then pls verify the same behaviour in 2.53 (any earlier versions of 3), add details.

Comment: @Naveen For now I'm trying it with selenium 3.0.1 and yes it opens `Firefox` & `IE` instead of `Chrome`, because of driver executable...and this is my question why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selenium project just attempts to launch the executeable and the request a new session from it. The problem here is that chromedriver readily accepts the new session request for "firefox", but it shouldn't.

It is a bug, actually, there was the thread regarding this on git hub for selenium board.
[If we pass chromedriver.exe for webdriver.gecko.driver , it works and opens chrome browser](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3306)

Hope it helps.